# Reading smart contract from malicious node

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, contract

With smart contracts, I know transactions are verified by multiple nodes, but reading only requires one node. What if that one node is malicious and gives out corrupted data? Is this possible?

Comment: This is a solely opinion based question. Not a Programming question, also does not meet the guidelines for a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ron Only debugging questions require an MRE/MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible for a node to be malicious and to return modified results (to either all queries or just selected ones).

Apart from non-technical ways to minimize the risk of retrieving data from a malicious node (e.g. request data only from reputable providers, ...), you can set up your own node that you have control over. Here are two widely used open-source Ethereum clients that you can run on your machine:

- https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started
- https://openethereum.github.io/index

Both are capable of communicating with external apps using the standardized [JSON RPC API](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API) (there are wrappers over this API, for example `web3` and `ethers.js` libraries).